# Using Compass to prefix -ms for flexbox

Tags: sass, compass-sass, flexbox, compass

I am trying to use the css3/flexbox mixin and I want compass to handle all the -ms prefixing and variants for IE10. Does anyone know how to to configure compass for this? All it pumps out is -webkit-flex, and I want it to do -ms-flex.

Answer (score -1):

I am just using bower install sass-flex-mixins. That package does exactly what I need without a lot of compass black box magic. I can use the mixins, and it works in IE10 and up no problem.